# what's the greedy or dynamic programming approach for this?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Suppose we are making sentences by using bi-gram, which means probability of appearance of each word is dependent on previous word. The probability of a sentence is multiple of probability of words

```
P(sentence) = p(t0)*multiple from i=1 to i=n p(ti|ti-1)
```

we have probability matrix which we can use to determine `P(ti|ti-1)`, we want to find the most probable sentence

Is there any greedy or dynamic programming approach for it?

Comment: Every `p(ti|ti-1) <= 1`, so `P(sentence) <= p(t0)`, that means the most probable sentence consists from one word with biggest probability.

Comment: this is not correct because we have some special characters in the begining and at the end of sentences.To be more clear,we have for example * at the begining with P(t0) and & at the end with P(tn|t0).Now if you put a new word between these two characters,may be the product of P(t0)*P(t1|t0)*P(tn|t1) is more than product of P(t0)*p(tn|t0).....so we must find the best choices

Comment: how long is the sentence? how many characters are there?

Comment: assume you have n unit words and you can use arbitrary number of words in a sentence.there is no limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Viterbi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm). Your states is a words (`t0, t2, t7, ...`). Your initial state is `t0` and you have a matrix with transition probabilities `a_i,j = P(tj|ti)`, you have no "observations", so you can not think about `P(y|k)`. For every length (`t`) and every word (`t_k`) you will find `V_t,k` that is the probability of the most probable sentence with `t` words and word `t_k` at the sentence's end.